# How to detect an interface in an object that was assigned to a base class variable in Dart?

Tags: inheritance, interface, dart

Consider a hierarchy of classes like so:

- There is a single base class, `BaseClass`
- There are many derived classes from `BaseClass`, some of which implement different interfaces

So for example, there's a class `DerivedClass` that extends `BaseClass` and implements `SomeInterface`.

Since I'm dealing with many different classes that all inherit from `BaseClass`, I figured that I would store their objects in a container like `List<BaseClass>`. But then I can't seem to figure out a way to detect an interface in those objects.

```
class SomeInterface {
  String field;
}

abstract class BaseClass {
  int count;

  BaseClass(this.count);
}

class DerivedClass extends BaseClass implements SomeInterface {
  String field;

  DerivedClass(int count, this.field) : super(count);
}

void printField(SomeInterface obj) {
  print(obj.field);
}

void main() {
  BaseClass item = DerivedClass(4, 'test');
  if (item is SomeInterface) {  // Attempt one
    print(item.field);
  }
  printField(item);  // Attempt two
}
```

Earlier I had `SomeInterface` in the inheritance chain like an actual superclass, but I'd like to stay away from that as interfaces are easier to handle in my case. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` works for implemented interfaces the same as for super classes.

So

```
if (item is SomeInterface) {
```

is the way to go.

As @attdona pointed out below, to access `SomeInterface` members after the `is` check a cast is still necessary.

See also

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35525
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35314

Comment: `item` has to be casted with `as` operator: `print((item as SomeInterface).field);`

Comment: I see. I didn't really understand what the question was about. I think it shouldn't be necessary when `item` is a variable as it can't change type between subsequent access. It would be different if `item` was a getter.

Comment: Like https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35314 https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35525